# complicated query entry mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, insert, foreach

I'm having great trouble with "INSERT INTO"...

I have a variable part number so this my code...:

```
<?php
include ("db_conn.php");

$mem_id = "1";
$descript = "chair";
$qualifier = "sitting";
$major = "Y";
$value = "6";
//$mesh_cell_string = "tree_0,tree_1,tree_2,tree_3,tree_4";
//$mesh_values_string = "'C23','550','291','687','500'";

$part_number = "C23.550.291.687.500";
$parts = explode('.', $part_number);

$n = 0;
foreach ($parts as $something => $number)
        {
        $mesh_cell_string .= "tree_" . $n  . ",";
        $mesh_values_string .=  "'" . $number . "'," ;

        $n++;
        }    

$mesh_values_string = substr($mesh_values_string, 0, -1);
$mesh_cell_string = substr($mesh_cell_string, 0, -1);




$insert_string = "mem_id,mesh_heading_name," . $mesh_cell_string . ",qualifier_name,major,rank";
$values_string = "'$mem_id','$descript'," .$mesh_values_string. ",'$qualifier','$major','$value'";  


$sql = "INSERT INTO mesh_table (" . $insert_string .") VALUES (" . $values_string .")";

$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql) or die ("couldn't execute the query");


?>
```

The strange thing is... i don't get an error ("couldn't execute the query") so i thought it went alright but when i look into my database there aren't any values written... when i un-comment the the 2 variables:

```
//$mesh_cell_string = "tree_0,tree_1,tree_2,tree_3,tree_4";
//$mesh_values_string = "'C23','550','291','687','500'";
```

And comment the foreach loop, it works...? So there goes something wrong in the foreach loop, but when i echo the $sql on both methods i get the same:

```
INSERT INTO mesh_table (mem_id,mesh_heading_name,tree_0,tree_1,tree_2,tree_3,tree_4,qualifier_name,major,rank) VALUES ('1','Chair','C23','550','291','687','500','sitting','Y','6')
```

I really don't know what i am doing wrong...?

Best regards,
Thijs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
change $values_string = "'$mem_id','$descript'," .$mesh_values_string. ",'$qualifier','$major','$value'";
```

To

```
$values_string = "'".$mem_id."','".$descript."'," .$mesh_values_string. ",'".$qualifier."','".$major."','".$value."'";
```

Comment: It worked... for one time, the strange thing is that if i "emptied the table" refresh the page that it won't write again... except if i change one value of the partnumber...? Is this some cache thing?